# Is time taken for enabling Performance Insights for RDS instance depends on the size?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am trying to enable performance insights for Postgres RDS from AWS console.
When I enabled this option I see that status of RDS instance is changed from "Available" to "Configuring enhanced monitoring". The instance state staid in this state around 2 minutes 30 seconds before it is changed to "Available" again. I tried this on two test RDS instances and it took about the same time. I have two questions on this.

1. Though below AWS documentation says that there is not downtime for enabling/disabling the performance insights it does actually requires downtime?
   (Please note that we don't have clustered RDS)

"You can turn on Performance Insights for your DB instance or Multi-AZ DB cluster when you create it. If needed, you can turn it off later. Turning Performance Insights on and off doesn't cause downtime, a reboot, or a failover."

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PerfInsights.Enabling.html

2. Does RDS size has impact on time taken for "Configuring enhanced monitoring"? As the Production RDS will have more data.

Please guide.